# List item not updating using SPServices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2007, spservices

I'm quite new to SPServices and trying to figure out how to perform a simple update on a list item upon click a button. What I have set up on my test site is a simple input button on each of the row's list item on the list view. For testing purposes I just want this button to update a field called "Notes" (this is Text Area input in case it matters) on my list named Severities and add a simple text saying "Updated".

The code below is what I came up with so far and there are a few things I'm not quite sure about. First thing is the ID; per what I read in documentation for SPServices, we need to specify an ID at all times. But in my case I would need to have that automated somehow so read a similar post about this similar issue and as per a thread it was suggested to use `var id = $(this).closest('tr')[0].id;` .

The second part I'm not so sure about is how to trigger the .click event. What I am hoping to accomplish is when the user presses the button (Input button with ID="feedback"), I want that to trigger the SPServices to update the list item's Notes field with "Updated". I added the following line for this:

```
$("#feedback").click(function() {
```

I feel like the rest should be fine but I would appreciate any feedback at this point.

Here is my button which is at the end of my TR row

```
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" id="feedback" />
```

Here is the JavaScript code in which I have added in a Content Webpart under the list.

```
<link type="text/css" href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="Scripts/SPServices/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#feedback").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr')[0].id;
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "Update",
            listName: "Severities",
            ID: id,
            valuepairs: [["Notes", "Updated"]],
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                alert("Dang");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I found a problem with the ID of my input button and made the changes. I am now getting an alert saying Dang, however my list item is still not being updated as expected. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you checked with ID: id instead of ID: 'id' ? after removing single quote(') as id is a variable.

Comment: Yeah sorry i fixed this afterwards but thanks for spotting that I edited my answer.